# How do I run Laravel Mailhog using PHP server

Tags: php, laravel, mailhog

I'm not able to install Homestead, so I'm using the command line below to run my  Laravel app

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public/
```

I'm trying to get Mailhog running. On my .env file, I set the mail driver as follows

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

If I go to http://localhost:8025/, I get "This site can't be reached"

Comment: you are suppose to visit. http://localhost:8000

Comment: The localhost:8000 displays the Laravel app. I tried php -S localhost:8025 -t public/, but it too displays the Laravel app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only reason that I know of that you would receive that error is if you haven't started mailhog. So, if that is the case, you need to open a terminal and type mailhog and then hit enter. That will start mailhog. Then you should be able to go to http://127.0.0.1:8025/ and mailhog will be available.

Comment: Hi, I'm using the Windows Command Prompt. I entered the directory of the Laravel app and executed the command 'mailhog'. I got the message 'mailhog' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Ok. On Windows, you should be able to double click on the Mailhog executable (.exe). That will open mailhog and then you should be able to access at http://127.0.0.1:8025/ . One note, mailhog should open a windows command prompt when you open it... Make sure you don't close the command prompt until you are ready to quit mailhog.

Comment: I downloaded the exe file from GitHub and ran the file. Worked liked magic! I am now able to get mailhog running. Much obliged :-)